# lua static analysis: detecting uninitialized table field

Tags: lua, static-analysis

I'm using luacheck (within the Atom editor), but open to other static analysis tools.

Is there a way to check that I'm using an uninitialized table field? I read the docs (http://luacheck.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) but maybe I missed how to do this?

In all three cases in the code below I'm trying to detect that I'm (erroneously) using field 'y1'. None of them do. (At run-time it is detected, but I'm trying to catch it before run-time).

```
local a = {}
a.x = 10
a.y = 20
print(a.x + a.y1)         -- no warning about uninitialized field y1 !?

-- luacheck: globals b
b = {}
b.x = 10
b.y = 20
print(b.x + b.y1)         -- no warning about uninitialized field y1 !?

-- No inline option for luacheck re: 'c', so plenty of complaints
-- about "non-standard global variable 'c'."
c = {}                    --   warning about setting
c.x = 10                  --   warning about mutating
c.y = 20                  --     "       "     "
print(c.x + c.y1)         --   more warnings (but NOT about field y1)
```

The point is this: as projects grow (files grow, and the number & size of modules grow), it would be nice to prevent simple errors like this from creeping in.

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/mpeterv/luacheck/issues/46 https://github.com/mpeterv/luacheck/issues/39 Simply it is not there.

Comment: Thanks -- good to know that I wasn't missing something, and that maybe it might get addressed in luacheck.

Comment: Indeed, accessing uninitialized fields is not on the list of issues luacheck detects: http://luacheck.readthedocs.io/en/stable/warnings.html. I plan to work on that.

Comment: Here something: http://lua-users.org/wiki/DetectingUndefinedVariables

Comment: @mpeterv - Thanks for letting me know. I'll pay attention to luacheck as it evolves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[lua-inspect](https://github.com/davidm/lua-inspect) should be able to detect and report these instances. I have it integrated into [ZeroBrane Studio IDE](http://studio.zerobrane.com/) and when running with the [deep analysis](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-general-preferences#static-analyzer) it reports the following on this fragment:

```
unknown-field.lua:4: first use of unknown field 'y1' in 'a'
unknown-field.lua:7: first assignment to global variable 'b'
unknown-field.lua:10: first use of unknown field 'y1' in 'b'
unknown-field.lua:14: first assignment to global variable 'c'
unknown-field.lua:17: first use of unknown field 'y1' in 'c'
```

(Note that the integration code only reports first instances of these errors to minimize the number of instances reported; I also fixed an issue that only reported first unknown instance of a field, so you may want to use the latest code from the [repository](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/).)

Comment: what I tried: ZeroBraneStudio Lua IDE, v1.4; Edit/Preferences/Settings:User with this line added: staticanalyzer.infervalue = false. Then do Project/Analyze -- I do get complaints about globals 'b' and 'c', but no mention of 'y1'. I'm very new (user for 10 minutes, now) so possible I didn't correctly do the "deep analysis" you mention.

Comment: @JLPLabs, use `staticanalyzer.infervalue = true`. To also get the reports about `b` and `c` you need to get the latest code from the repository (as 1.4 doesn't have some of the latest changes).

Comment: This works nicely when the table is local and keys are constant but I get numerous false positives when analyzing "real" code. It appears that when lua-inspect can't infer type of a value it produces a warning each time it's indexed.

Comment: @mpeterv, you are right; the type inference is limited. That's why I limited the report to only the first instance of the field when it was integrated with ZeroBrane Studio.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko - Thanks! It works as advertised. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

People who look into questions related to "Lua static analysis" may also be interested in the various dialects of **typed Lua**, for example:

- [Typed Lua](https://github.com/andremm/typedlua)
- [Titan](https://github.com/titan-lang/titan)
- [Pallene](https://github.com/pallene-lang/pallene)
- [Ravi](https://github.com/dibyendumajumdar/ravi)

But you may not have heard of "[Teal](https://github.com/teal-language/tl)". (early in its life it was called "tl"); .

I'm taking the liberty to answer my original question using Teal, since I find it intriguing.

```
-- 'record' (like a 'struct')
local Point = record
   x : number
   y : number
end

local a : Point = {}
a.x = 10
a.y = 20
print(a.x + a.y1)   -- will trigger an error
                    -- (in VS Code using teal extension & at command line)
```

From command line:

```
> tl check myfile.tl
========================================
1 error:
myfile.tl:44:13: invalid key 'y1' in record 'a'
```

By the way...

```
> tl gen myfile.tl'
```

creates a pure Lua file: 'myfile.lua' that has **no type** information in it. Note: running this Lua file will trigger the 'nil' error... lua: myfile.lua:42: attempt to index a nil value (local 'a').

So, Teal gives you a chance to catch 'type' errors, but it doesn't require you to fix them before generating Lua files.